# Bash , running a command from inside a vi file and substituting the value of the command

Tags: bash, unix

I have a file ProjectID.lst with content

```
13217
13214
```

I have another file

Report.lst with content

```
Aggregation|`sed -n '1p' ProjectID.lst`|`sed -n '2p' ProjectID.lst
```

When i do cat Report.lst , i want the following o/p to come

```
Aggregation|13217|13214
```

Could you suggest how to do this. the approach i am following is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You  can try this way

```
cat Report.lst
#!/bin/bash
echo "Aggregation|`sed -n '1p' ProjectID.lst`|`sed -n '2p' ProjectID.lst`"
```

or simply use one `sed` command

```
echo "Aggregation|`sed  'N;s/\n/|/' ProjectID.lst`"
```

**Run:**

```
bash Report.lst
```

**Output :**

```
Aggregation|13217|13214
```

**Explanation :**

`cat` command only print the content of the file ,shell will execute the back tic and take the exact result .Then you need to print the output using echo statement .

Answer (score 0):

`:!<shell command>` filters the highlighted text through the given external command. You can highlight an empty line with `V`, then call `:!<command>` to have the (empty) line replaced with the output of `<command>`.

The description of what you want to do is a bit too fuzzy for me to come up with an adaption of the above to your specific needs.